# Can I check what exactly is causing a broadcastreceiver to be triggered?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have a BroadcastReceiver that's registered like this in my manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.LaunchReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ACTION_PULSE_SERVER_ALARM" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The problem is that it's sometimes triggered 6-7 times in a row for no apparent reason. Is there a way to check what exactly is triggering it?

I've tried

```
Log.d("LaunchReceiver", "intent.getAction(): " + intent.getAction());    
Log.d("LaunchReceiver", "intent.getDataString(): " + intent.getDataString());
Log.d("LaunchReceiver", "intent.getType(): " + intent.getType());
```

But they're all always null.

I've also tried

```
NetworkInfo ni = cnnxManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

Log.d("LaunchReceiver", "ni.getTypeName(): " + ni.getTypeName());
Log.d("LaunchReceiver", "ni.getExtraInfo(): " + ni.getExtraInfo());
Log.d("LaunchReceiver", "ni.getState().name(): " + ni.getState().name());
Log.d("LaunchReceiver", "ni.isFailover(): " + ni.isFailover());
```

But they don't change...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: 
It seems to be connected with network state changes. When I switched from mobile net to wifi just now it triggered 4 times with

```
intent.getAction(): android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

Then it triggered once more for no apparent reason, for a total of 5 times.

Edit2:
When switching from wifi to mobile net I get a whole lot of this:

```
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET]_files_getaddrinfo+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET]_files_getaddrinfo-,1
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET]_dns_getaddrinfo+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET]_dns_getaddrinfo-,3
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit,err=7
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit,err=8
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname+
08-02 16:45:18.074: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname-
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy-,2
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_files_getaddrinfo+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_files_getaddrinfo-,1
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_dns_getaddrinfo+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_dns_getaddrinfo-,3
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit,err=7
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit,err=8
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname-
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy-,2
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_files_getaddrinfo+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_files_getaddrinfo-,1
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_dns_getaddrinfo+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]_dns_getaddrinfo-,3
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit,err=7
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit,err=8
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname+
08-02 16:45:18.084: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname-
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit,err=8
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] ht 0x66772e776f6c66
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 14, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname+
08-02 16:45:18.094: D/libc(24471): [NET] check propname-
08-02 16:45:18.354: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy-,1
08-02 16:45:18.354: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit 1
08-02 16:45:18.354: D/libc(24471): [NET]android_getaddrinfo_proxy-,1
08-02 16:45:18.354: D/libc(24471): [NET] getaddrinfo-exit 1
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): killProcess, pid=24471
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:1004)
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:123)
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
08-02 16:45:48.967: D/Process(24471): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does this make sense to anyone? I think this might be connected to using RemObjects SDK though...

Edit 3:

I've removed the last intent-filter as it seems to be redundant. Still getting 3 triggers on connectionchanges, which doesn't really make sense. 2, one for wifi/mobile disconnecting, and one for the other connecting, would make sense. They all also say

```
intent.getAction(): android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

and

```
ni.getDetailedState().name(): CONNECTED.
```

Weird stuff

Answer (score 0):

As you would know the broadcast reciever gets called when particular intent is hit,So I think whenever connectivity changes all the intents that you defined is passed like if wifi network is connected then the following intents will be called:

action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE"

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out which one exactly is triggering it when it gets triggered

Comment: It does seem to be connected with network state changes though. When I switched from mobile net to wifi just now it triggered 4 times with intent.getAction(): android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ... Then it triggered once more for no apparent reason, for a total of 5 times.

Comment: I think you've put me on the right track here, so thanks for that :)

Comment: I think to debug you could put differnt combinations of the 4 intents like put one intent and see what happens and then 2 etc... This way you could see which intent or intent is causing problems.... and could see the alternatives...